# Migrating from SQL Membership Provider to Indentity 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, asp.net-identity

I'm using EF, Webforms .net 4.5 for a rebuild of our web application.

We have 4000 users in our databases which are the standard databases from the membership provider.

How can I go about this migration without losing all of the users passwords?

I've spend 9 hours trying to make this work from the article below:
http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity

But the problem is that's for identity 1.0 and it's completely obsolete.

I've tried going to the PMC and updating the database that way, but all it does it create new tables for identity without importing any of the old data. Even if I imported the data myself the password hashing differences from the cyrpto changes wouldn't allow me to log in if I just copied the salt and hashes.

What am I missing here? I've spent over 12 hours trying to figure out this migration and have gotten any where, there is a huge lack of documentation for web forms.

Comment: The article you linked has it all - there is a sql script to move data from old tables into new ones. Also there is a password hasher that works with the migrated passwords. Also the article does not talks about MVC nor Web-forms but is geared towards web-forms (mentioning Register.aspx.cs). I've migrated 2 projects to Identity following this article, so it is complete. Just try again.

Comment: @trailmax it's for identity 1 and doesn't work with identity 2.0, so I don't doubt what you say, but you haven't done it with 2.0

Comment: That's exactly what I've done - migrated from MembershipProvider to Identity 2.0 and then another project to 2.1. Using this article both times. In terms of migration v1 is not much different from v2. What are your exact problems?

Comment: @trailmax then how did you get past the problems with the different tables such as discriminator, email confirmation? I keep encountering base-64 error on login if I manually edit the database to work.

Comment: let me clarify, this article does work for 1.0 and you can do it with 2.0 installed. However it still retains the old database structure with the discriminator column and other stuff, i'm trying to update it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generated the new migration and copied from the old identity tables and it works.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blmkPA7XQf8